# resetting a div after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm having an issue with trying to reset a div, containing an image, to the original value after I have animated it.

So I have a sort of quiz with 6 pictures positioned next to each other.
The user has to select one of 6 pictures. When clicked on that picture I make the picture go fullscreen. Afterwards, when the user doubleclicks on the picture the picture should go back to the original position for the next question.

However the return is not working and I don't understand why.

Beware: the divsare floated divs with specific left-positions so I would need to retain these...

This is the animation-code:

```
$(".candidatePicture").click(function(e){
      $(e.target).css('z-index', 1); 
      $(e.target).animate({top: '0', left: '0', width: '1920px', height: '1080px'}, 1000);
    });
```

This is the return code:

```
$(".candidatePicture").css({ 'width': '250px', 'height': '300px', 'z-index': '0' });
```

You can find the code here: http://jsbin.com/gotuqenoce

Thank you for your help.

Comment: wouldn't css animation / transition based on class change be better?

Comment: Can you animate from one css-class to another?

Comment: With transition - sure you can. I'll prepare fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/of1n2t0z/1/

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've tried it out but there are two issues with this. The divs are on different left-offsets and the picture does not transition from the current position, but jumps to the new left- and top-position and performs the animation from there

Comment: can you post working copy or fiddle URL? This sounds odd.

Comment: see (https://jsfiddle.net/nwzmmjtz/)

Comment: Hi Komal, this seems to be working fine, thank you. I've only modified it slightly to set my z-index to 1 before performing the switchClass.

Comment: that i have commented and added into the class - divanimate for maintaining the css style at one place.

Comment: Komal,which version of JQuery are you using in the jsFiddle because in my local version it doesn't work...

Comment: it might be due to i have used jquery(1.9.1) jquery ui( 1.9.2)

Comment: Bingo! That was it ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please try to change the events handlers as follow:

```
$(".candidatePicture").click(function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.css('z-index', 1); 
  $this.animate({top: '0', left: '0', width: '1920px', height: '1080px'}, 1000);
  $this.off("click");
});
$( ".candidatePicture" ).dblclick(function(e) {
  $(this).css({ top: '', left: '', 'width': '', 'height': '', 'z-index': '' });
  showNextQuestion();
});
```

http://jsbin.com/latiqemozo/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks itacode, but when I try this, it resets my z-index fine but the picture stays full screen and is not resized to 250px X 300px